# Problema con useEffect en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, useeffect

tengo el siguiente codigo de `React`:

```
export function AccountActivation() {
    const props = useLocation().state
    console.log(props)
    const {register, handleSubmit, formState:{errors}} = useForm()
    let [userActivated, setUserActivated] = useState(false)
    let [realActivationCode, setRealActivationCode] = useState(null)
    let [mailSended, setMailSended] = useState(false)
    const sendMail = async ()=>{
        const response = await sendActivationEmailAPI(props.userEmail, props.username)
        console.log('enviando correo de activacion')
        setRealActivationCode(response)
        setMailSended(true)
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        if (!mailSended){
            sendMail()
        }
    }, [])
    const onSubmit = handleSubmit(async (data)=>{
        if (Number(data.activation_code) === Number(realActivationCode)){
            try {
                const response = await activateUserAPI(props.userId)
                if (response.status === 200){
                    console.log('Exito activando el usuario')
                    console.log(response)
                    setUserActivated(true)
                } else {
                    console.log('Error activando usuario')
                    console.log(response)
                }
            } catch(error){
                console.log('Error activando el usuario')
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
    })
    if (userActivated === true){
        return <Navigate to="/login/"/>
    } else{
        return (
            <>
                <Header/>
                <div>
                    <h1>
                        Ingresa el código de activación
                    </h1>
                    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                        <FormField label="Codigo " errors={errors.activation_code && errors.activation_code.message}>
                            <input 
                                type="text"
                                maxLength={6}
                                minLength={1}
                                name="activation_code"
                                id="activation_code"
                                {...register("activation_code", {
                                    required : {
                                        value : true,
                                        message : "Por favor ingresa un código de activación"
                                    },
                                    pattern : {
                                        value : /^-?\d+$/,
                                        message : "Por favor, ingresa un codigo valido"
                                    },
                                    minLength : {
                                        value : 6,
                                        message : 'Debes ingresar al menos 6 caracteres',
                                    }
                                    })}
                            />
                        <button type="submit">enviar</button>
                        </FormField>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Tengo la necesidad de hacer que la funcion `sendMail()` se ejecute unicamente una vez (la primera vez que el `comp` sea renderizado), pues la funcion se esta ejecutando dos veces por alguna razon desconocida. Alguien tiene alguna idea?

Comment: estas corriendo tu aplicacion dentro de las etiquetas <React.StrictMode> ?

Comment: Si, ese era justamente el problema, ya esta solucionado.

Answer (score 1):

**El problema que estás enfrentando con useEffect es que la función sendMail se ejecuta en un ciclo infinito de renderizado debido a que no has incluido las dependencias en el segundo argumento del useEffect.

Cuando proporcionas un arreglo vacío ([]) como segundo argumento del useEffect, le estás diciendo que la función de efecto solo se debe ejecutar una vez, después del primer renderizado. Sin embargo, la función sendMail actualiza el estado (setMailSended(true)) y, debido a que mailSended cambia, el efecto se ejecuta nuevamente, lo que a su vez vuelve a llamar a sendMail, creando un ciclo infinito.

Para solucionar esto, debes incluir mailSended como dependencia en el arreglo de dependencias del useEffect. Esto hará que el efecto se vuelva a ejecutar solo cuando mailSended cambie su valor. Aquí tienes el código modificado:**

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (!mailSended) {
    sendMail();
  }
}, [mailSended]);
```

**Con esta modificación, el efecto solo se ejecutará cuando mailSended cambie su valor de false a true. Esto asegurará que sendMail se ejecute una vez y no cause un ciclo infinito de renderizado.

Además, ten en cuenta que si sendActivationEmailAPI es una función asíncrona, es posible que también desees manejar los errores que pueda lanzar**

Comment: Asegúrate de [no utilizar ChatGPT](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5462): está prohibido aquí.

Comment: @juancruz Esa era una parte del problema, sin embargo, el problema principal es que el <StrictMode> de React ejecuta dos veces el useeffect en desarrollo.

Comment: @PySanti si queres subi el codigo entero y lo miro en detalle!